# Apache htdocs folder

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-9.04

Where is the folder that contains the index.htm(l) that contains "it's working", located in Ubuntu?

Comment: OK. It's a newbie question but no reason to down vote. If you do feel like down voting a newbie question then please leave a comment why you think it deserved a down vote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [http://packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/all/apache2-doc/filelist), the documentation for apache is in /usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/.

If however, you're refering to the DocumentRoot, the default location is /var/www.

Comment: And if for some reason it's not in the default location the config file will tell you where it is.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/apache2/sites-available will tell tell you what sites are where.
Additional software that runs on apache often goes there with a separate file and its own directory.